# Webpack throws an error when compiling an application when cubejs is imported

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When I try to import cubejs into my react project and build it using webpack, I get the error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR

./node_modules/@cubejs-client/react/dist/cubejs-client-react.esm.js 8:21
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:21)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| class QueryRenderer extends React.Component {
>   static contextType = CubeContext;
|   static defaultProps = {
|     cubejsApi: null,
```

My code
webpack.config.js:

```
"use strict";

var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.jsx",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public"),
    chunkFilename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.js(x)?$/],
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "./indexTemplate.html"),
      templateParameters: {
        build: Date.now(),
      },
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/index.html"),
      inject: false,
      minify: false,
    }),
  ],
};
```

If I rename file cubejs-client-react.esm.js -> cubejs-client-react.esm.jsx, the error disappears.

But this is a bad solve, Because the file is located in node_modules

Comment: how are u using cubejs in your code

Comment: @Yilmaz Just import cubejs-client/react module.
I'm attaching cubejs:

`import { QueryBuilder as CubeQuery } from "@cubejs-client/react";`
So I use:
    `<CubeQuery cubejsApi={cubejsApi} resetResultSetOnChange={false} render {(props) => {return <div>CubeQuery</div>}}/>`